# Burger Button missing on android when navigating further in the Navigation Stack

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, navigation, prism, master-detail

Basically, my problem is described exactly in
[this bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42548).

I have this issue only in my Android project. It works fine on iOS.
Do you know a solution or workaround for this?
I don't want to create a new NavigationPage, so that workaround will not work in my approach. If there is another solution, it would be very helpful.

**Edit:** a sample code can be found [here](https://github.com/begreal/MasterDetailSample)

Comment: Could you show some code or image to explain the problem? This shared link is been a long time ago. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page

Comment: Have you seen the bugzilla report? Like i said, there is nothing different in my application. An image is also attached to the report.

Comment: You mean the bug reappear,which version of vs? Could you share a sample project,i will check it.

Comment: Well, the bug was never gone i think. I am using both vs for mac community 2017 and 2019 but what does it have to do with the ide?

Comment: I'll add the sample code later

Comment: Recently vs has some updated.Before this problem has been solved.I do not know why this happen again.I just guess that may be related to vs.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/begreal/MasterDetailSample) is the code sample. sorry that it took so long

Comment: link-only questions should be off-topic the same way as link-only answers

Comment: @BeytullahGüneyli Thanks for link.I got it.This problem should be related to prism.It is not the same with the bug link.Suggest that updating nuget package in your project.I find some are latest and some are before long version ,such as XF version ,etc.